# Unable to bind to port 80 [bitnami, OSQA, Ubuntu 12.04]

Tags: 12.04, apache2

For some reason I can't open port 80, so my install is using 8080.

how can I find the exact service using port 80 and terminate it or uninstall it?

Comment: Are u running the application the in admin mode. Because you need to admin permissions to bind to any port below 1000.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what processes are using which ports, you can use the '-p' option to netstat (this must be done as root).  the command I always use is:

```
sudo netstat -alutp
```

This shows all open, listening, udp, tcp sockets, and what process has them open.

Answer (score 0):

you downloaded the stack instead of the module. go to https://bitnami.com/stack/xampp?utm_campaign=XAMPP%2BModule&utm_medium=installer&utm_source=bitnami to get the module that works with xampp